Integral of non-continuous function
I am trying to solve what appears to be a simple integration problem from this paper that I am trying to implement.

Where $z$ and $\lambda(z)$ have discrete values:

As the values of $z$ and $\lambda(z)$ are not continuous it has completely stumped me. Can anyone please offer me some guidence on how to compute this integral?

$\lambda$ should have domain (at least) $(0,\infty)$ for this integral to be defined. What is $\lambda(x)$ when $x$ is not one of those special values?

I suspect that you have here implicitly a discrete measure. Therefore, if you define $z_1 = 100, z_2 = 200..., z_6=5000$, you just have
$$\int_0^\infty z \lambda(z) dz = \sum_{i=1}^6 z_i \lambda(z_i).$$

I do believe this is the right approach. Thank you!
